# Identify website from which user was redirected to current site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

How can I know the web-site from which the user was directed to my web-site?

For example, when user on site1.com clicks a button/ anchor tag and is redirected to mysite.com, I should be able to infer the web-site (or IP address and the port) from which the request was obtained.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using UrlReferrer property of Request.

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Include this namespace first:

```
System.Web
```

Comment: I have tried it. But it is not consisent and does not work everytime (rather most of the time and I need this to work across browsers). As per msdn, we might get this value when redirected from an anchor tag. But it is not necessary, that the user is redirected to my site by clicking hyperlink !!!

Comment: That's because the referrer can be left blank or altered by the client, and will be blank when a link is clicked from an HTTPS page. Nothing you can do, other than adding an URL parameter like `&source=externalsitename` when sharing the link.